# Casting node to element giving ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, nodes, xmlnodelist

here n2 is my NodeList, and i just want to see the first child node of my root element

```
public void ClickMe(View view){


    Node rootElement=n2.item(0);
    NodeList child=rootElement.getChildNodes();

    Node first=child.item(0);
    //ClassCastException error is coming whenever i am casting first to Element.

    Element nm=(Element)first;

    Option q= getOption(nm,first);
    Log.i(TAG,"the name is was talking about is : "+ q.getName());
}
```

this what logcat says

```
07-31 20:32:38.376: E/AndroidRuntime(2950): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.TextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
```

Comment: first is a Node, not an Element, so you cannot downcast it explicitly

Comment: i have implemented this downcasting in my DOM parser , and there it is working perfectly fine, but here it gives an error.

Comment: whitespace will kill you.  It's pretty clear that the first Node is not actually an Element.

Comment: You would need to perform type-checking as other answers suggest in order to safely do the downcast. As any non Element object will not get into the downcasted object, it will run fine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try it like this....

```
NodeList LOP = odoc.getElementsByTagName("Your_XML_Top_Element");

                Node FPN =LOP.item(0);
                try{
                if(FPN.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    {

                    Element token = (Element)FPN;

                    NodeList oNameList1 = token.getElementsByTagName("Your_XML_Sub_Node");
                    Element firstNameElement = (Element)oNameList1.item(0);
                    NodeList textNList1 = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();

}
```

Comment: see i don't want to fetch nodes with tag names, i want to fetch them using indexes.. is it possible ?

Comment: even you are doing the same casting, 
 Element token=(Element)FPN;
in my case it is giving errors, how is that so?

Comment: Because he filters on **Element** nodes. Not every Node in an xml document is an **Element**! The magic in this code is the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

If node is element then only cast it. Make check like below.

```
if (first.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { Element nm=(Element)first;}
```