# GWT : remove a class from the sibling

Tags: java, gwt

```
<select:Select ui:field="valueBox" addStyleNames="{style.valueBox}">
  <select:Option text="text1"/>   
  <select:Option text="text2"/>
</select:Select>
```

The above lines produce native HTML as:

```
<select class="bootstrap-select form-control" style="display: none;">...</select>
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control">
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle form-control selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown">..</button>
...few more lines...
```

How can I remove the `btn` and `btn-default` class from `<button/>` from my java code?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
((Element) valueBox.getElement().getNextSibling().getNextSibling()).removeClassName("btn");
```

Be careful while [casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822719/casting-node-to-element-giving-classcastexception) `Node` to `Element` as not every node is an element.

The more elegant solution could be to wrap the whole select in a container and use jQuery to get the button element like this:

```
$wnd.jQuery("#container_id button").removeClass("btn");
```